# how i can update the value of object of array by use state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, use-state, mern

I recently started learning react.js for making my final year project using MERN stack
during this i am facing this issue, i.e. i have an array

```
let projectTech = ['js','node','react'];
```

and i want to concat it with **technologies** array present in following useState, please tell me how can i do it.

```
const [projectObj, setProjectObj] = useState({                 
        title: '',
        type: '',
        link: '',
        technologies:[],
        role:'',
        description: ''
    });
```

i already tried following combinations but it's not working, after `console.log(projectObj.technologies)` i got empty array.

```
setProjectObj({...projectObj,technologies: projectTech});
setProjectObj({...projectObj,technologies:[...projectTech]});
setProjectObj({...projectObj,technologies:[...projectObj.technologies,projectTech]});
```

please help me, how can i fix this?

Comment: Can you show where you perform `console.log`? `setState` is an async operation, so you will not see the updated state immediatly after setting it

Comment: What does the end result you want look like? Also, neither of your first two attempts should give you a blank array, which suggests there's some *other* problem going on. Please update your question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, ideally a **runnable** one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button). Stack Snippets support React, including JSX; [here's how to do one](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338537/).

Comment: @yadejo i am performming ```console.log``` at the time of form submission, yes you are right it not showing at first time 0th index at console but i used this statemet into form submition, and i submit the form multiple time it still showing me blank array.

Comment: But it matters _how_ you're logging the state as yadejo mentioned. As you can see [the code works](https://jsfiddle.net/hpn10q29/) but because the state update is an batched async process you can't immediately log the state after you've updated it. Does adding `useEffect(() => console.log(projectObj), [projectObj]);` do anything to help? [That will detect changes in state, and log the updated object.](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder  @Andy  @yadejo I realy appreciate your respose, i know this think before, but my problem is assigning values of ```projectTech``` array to ```projectObj.technologies``` array. not console the values of ```projectObj.technologies```. however i fixed this problem by using ```projectObj.technologies.push([...projectTech])``` it worked for me, thank you !!

Comment: I'm not sure how you were doing this, for me your code worked, check this https://codesandbox.io/s/nifty-browser-wmoseu?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 1):

You can try using the prevState of the setState function.

```
setProjectObj((prevState) => ({...prevState, technologies: projectTech }))
```

**check out this: https://codesandbox.io/s/nifty-browser-wmoseu?file=/src/App.js**

Answer (score 0):

Nothing is wrong with that code. You only have to change how you console.log your result.

Since setting state is async, try to avoid logging state after setting it.

Add this in your component

```
const handleSetState = () => {
setProjectObj({...projectObj,technologies: projectTech});
console.log(projectObj) //WRONG, will console.log previous data
}

const handleSetState2 = () => {
const newObj = {...projectObj,technologies: projectTech}
setProjectObj(newObj);
console.log(newObj) //OK, but not actual state.
}

//BEST
useEffect(() => {
console.log(projectObj) //Console.log state
}, [projectObj]) //But only if state changes
```

Comment: I realy appreciate your respose, i know this think before, but my problem is assigning values of ```projectTech``` array to ```projectObj.technologies``` array. not console the values of ```projectObj.technologies```. however i fixed this problem by using ```projectObj.technologies.push([...projectTech])``` it worked for me, thank you sir!!

Comment: Oh sorry, I misread your question. I'm glad you figured it out!